# How can I unveal files on my external hard drive?

Tags: files, filesystems, osx, hard-disk, data-recovery

I copied a big folder (around 110 GB) from my (Mac 10.7.5) computer onto a hard drive (exFAT).

It took quite some time and afterwards I even checked that the files were actually there.

After more copying of other folders, I deleted all the source folders on my computer (and also the trash can) and unplugged the harddrive. Then I saw that the big folder on my hard drive was empty, not containing any data (the other folders are still there).

When analyzing the hard drive (under linux) I found this:

[image: Properties of the Partition Miel]

So it seems that the sum of all files only makes up 680 GB while there are actually 799 GB used!

The difference is probably the exact size of my missing data.

Is there any way to access or unveal this data?

Additional info:

- I named the Folder MASTER. But now there are two folders there. One is named MASTER and one is named Master.
- Both folders are completly empty, there are no hidden files.

Comment: Is `unveal` a real word?

Comment: Nope...I guess the word is unveil. Sorry. And of course I write that word in the title ;)

Comment: You could look for deleted file recovery tools.